# Get nid from node table in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am new in Drupal and using Drupal6. I need a help to get "nid" field from "node" table.

I have added some data in node table from admin side. Currently it is listed in view.tpl page page perfectly.For some other needs I need to get "nid" also.

I understand that the array name is $row and it contains the data. But i couldn't find from where this $row comes, so I couldnt edit $row.
Currently "nid" is not included in that array, see -

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [created] => 09-11-11
        [title] => Co-Sponsors Golf Events
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [created] => 09-09-12
        [title] => Co-Sponsors Golf Events2
    )
```

I want to include node id in $ row, like this -

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [created] => 09-11-11
        [title] => Co-Sponsors Golf Events
        [nid] => 3748
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [created] => 09-09-12
        [title] => Co-Sponsors Golf Events2
        [nid] => 3747
    )
```

I tried admin side of D-6 (content management>content type>edit , then manage field), but I couldn't find any option. I think from admin side we can manage 
the fields in $row OR can we pragmatically do this ?

Please let me know if my question is not clear and help me with detail description

Answer (score 0):

Are you using views module to get the data?..Which page is this content displayed. This is most probably a view page and to get the nid in the template, you need to edit the corresponding view (you need to figure out which view is generating the content) and add a field content: nid there. $row is basically the data views generate for a single row. After doing this you will have nid in the $row variable.